# VB add 2 numbers

Tags: vb.net

This may seem simple but I am confused. I have much experience with VB, this is not a spam question.

Result of label should be its previous value plus the new sales value entered. How is this code incorrect?

```
Option Strict Off

Public Class Form1

Dim totalpointsaccumultator As Object

Private Sub exitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles exitButton.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Public Sub assignButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles assignButton.Click
    Dim inputProjectPoints, inputTestPoints As String
    Dim grade, projectpoints, testpoints As String
    Dim projectcounter As Integer = 1
    Dim testcounter As Integer = 1
    Dim isconverted As Boolean
    Dim totalpointsaccumulator As Integer
    Do While projectcounter < 5
        inputProjectPoints = InputBox("Enter the points earned on project " & projectcounter, "Grade Calculator", "0")
        inputProjectPoints = projectpoints
        isconverted = Integer.TryParse(inputProjectPoints, CInt(projectpoints))
        If isconverted Then
            totalpointsaccumultator = totalpointsaccumulator + projectpoints
            projectcounter = projectcounter + 1
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number.", "Grade Calculator", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If
    Loop

    Do While testcounter < 3
        inputTestPoints = InputBox("Enter the points earned on test " & testcounter, "Grade Calculator", "0")
        isconverted = Integer.TryParse(inputTestPoints, testpoints)
        If isconverted Then
            testcounter = testcounter + 1
            totalpointsaccumulator = CInt(totalpointsaccumulator + testpoints)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number.", "Grade calculator", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If
    Loop

    ' assign grade
    Select Case totalpointsaccumulator
        Case Is >= 360
            grade = "A"
        Case Is >= 320
            grade = "B"
        Case Is >= 280
            grade = "C"
        Case Is >= 240
            grade = "D"
        Case Else
            grade = "F"
    End Select
    totalpointsLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(totalpointsaccumulator)
    gradeLabel.Text = grade
End Sub
```

End Class

EDIT: I revised this with Option Strict in mind, works now, thanks to all for ideas and help.

Option Explicit On

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub exitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles exitButton.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Public Sub assignButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles assignButton.Click

    For counter = 1 To 4
        Dim grade = InputBox("Grade " & counter)
        Do Until IsNumeric(grade) = True
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number.", "Grade Calculator", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            grade = InputBox("Grade " & counter)
        Loop
        Dim totalgrade = 0
        totalgrade = totalgrade + grade
        Select Case totalgrade
            Case Is >= 360
                grade = "A"
            Case Is >= 320
                grade = "B"
            Case Is >= 280
                grade = "C"
            Case Is >= 240
                grade = "D"
            Case Else
                grade = "F"
        End Select
        totalpointsLabel.Text = totalgrade
        gradeLabel.Text = grade
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: _"How is this code incorrect?"_ Any pointers on which part we should be looking at, or what is not working properly?

Comment: Also: `Option Strict Off` Really?  Best thing you can do in a new VB project is turn _on_ `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit`

Comment: You aset setting inputProjectPoints from user input but on the next line you overwrite it with projectpoints. I don't understand that part.

Answer (score 1):

you have a misspelling of your object totalpointsaccumul**t**ator and totalpointsaccumulator ...

and i don´t see the need for

```
Dim totalpointsaccumultator As Object
'                     ^ here´s your mistake
```

outside your function

I think your code should be like that:

```
Option Explicit On

Public Class Form1

' Dim totalpointsaccumultator As Object
' ^ this line removed 

Private Sub exitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles exitButton.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Public Sub assignButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles assignButton.Click
    Dim inputProjectPoints, inputTestPoints As String
    Dim grade, projectpoints, testpoints As String
    Dim projectcounter As Integer = 1
    Dim testcounter As Integer = 1
    Dim isconverted As Boolean
    Dim totalpointsaccumulator As Integer
    Do While projectcounter < 5
        inputProjectPoints = InputBox("Enter the points earned on project " & projectcounter, "Grade Calculator", "0")
        inputProjectPoints = projectpoints
        isconverted = Integer.TryParse(inputProjectPoints, CInt(projectpoints))
        If isconverted Then
            totalpointsaccumulator = totalpointsaccumulator + projectpoints
            '                 ^ "t" removed
            projectcounter = projectcounter + 1
            totalpointsLabel.Text = totalpointsaccumulator.ToString()
            ' new 
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number.", "Grade Calculator", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If
    Loop

    Do While testcounter < 3
        inputTestPoints = InputBox("Enter the points earned on test " & testcounter, "Grade Calculator", "0")
        isconverted = Integer.TryParse(inputTestPoints, testpoints)
        If isconverted Then
            testcounter = testcounter + 1
            totalpointsaccumulator = totalpointsaccumulator + testpoints
            '                        ^ cint( not needed
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number.", "Grade calculator", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If
    Loop

    ' assign grade
    Select Case totalpointsaccumulator
        Case Is >= 360
            grade = "A"
        Case Is >= 320
            grade = "B"
        Case Is >= 280
            grade = "C"
        Case Is >= 240
            grade = "D"
        Case Else
            grade = "F"
    End Select
    ' totalpointsLabel.Text = totalpointsaccumulator.ToString()
    gradeLabel.Text = grade
End Sub
```

Comment: ah, you want to see the actual value AFTER a single entry? then you have to move the "totalpointslabel.text = " .... into the loop ... I´ll change the codesample ...

Comment: Thanks, I have taken ideas from your code and others, new code is above, which works.